# Why in zsh setopt command and $- are not the same?

Tags: zsh

I am using zsh and if I type `setopt` it shows

```
autocd
nobeep
extendedglob
interactive
login
monitor
shinstdin
zle
```

- counts 8.

while if I type `echo $-` it shows :

```
569BJXZilms
```

- counts 11.

Why `$-` gives more options?

Answer (score 1):

`setopt` will only show the options which are changed from the default:

> Options that are on by default for the emulation are
>                 shown with the prefix `no` only  if  they  are  off,  while  other
>                 options are shown without the prefix `no` and only if they are on.
>                 In addition to options changed from the  default  state  by  the
>                 user,  any  options  activated  automatically  by the shell (for
>                 example, `SHIN_STDIN` or `INTERACTIVE`) will be shown in  the  list.

The options which are on by default are marked with a `<Z>` in the `zshooptions(1)` manpage. For example:

> ```
> NOTIFY (-5, ksh: -b) <Z>
> ```

which appears in `$-`, but not in the output of `setopt`.